# Why second create directory gives an error?

Tags: c#, io, create-directory

I want to transfer txt and sql extentions files in their spesific folders. In the below method first createdirectory works well but second gives an IOException error and says me there is already a folder with same name.

What do I miss ?

```
    private void InstallProgram()
    {
        string _sql = "sql";
        string _txt = "txt";
        DirectoryInfo d = new DirectoryInfo(executpath);
        string destdir = Path.Combine(executpath,_sql);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destdir);        // This works 
        string[] filebox = Directory.GetFiles(executpath, "*." + _sql);
        foreach(var item in filebox)
            File.Move(item,Path.Combine(destdir,Path.GetFileName(item)));
        destdir = Path.Combine(executpath, _txt);
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destdir);     // Where I get the error
        filebox = Directory.GetFiles(executpath, "*." + _txt);
        foreach (var item in filebox)
            File.Move(item,Path.Combine(destdir,Path.GetFileName(item)));
    }
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s(v=vs.110).aspx) states that _"If the directory **already exists**, this method does not create a new directory, but it returns a `DirectoryInfo` object for the existing directory."_ I doubt that they lie.

Comment: OTOH, it will throw an IOException if there is a *file* of that name already there. Have you read the exception message correctly?

Comment: @TimSchmelter there is no such directory.. I delete all directories (sql and txt) before running this method..

Comment: step through with a debugger, what does destdir contain at the moment of truth. If you suspect something funky is happening then run sysinternals procmon, this will show every real file system operation and the result of each one

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever you're right. There is no directory but during a test as I created unvolontairly a file called txt and as I seeking for directories so it was not working. Thanks.